# Datestamps changed days after question or answer posted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, timestamps, posting

I posted a meta question a couple weeks back about receiving notifications sporadically or not at all from forum activity. I think I may have moved a step closer to the problem origin:

This morning I received an email saying there were 3 answers to a question I posted yesterday, even though the question and the 3 answers were posted 5 days ago. But the notification system is *not* the problem: when I visited the web site to view the question and the answers they all claim they were posted *yesterday*, which is flatly false!!

So sometimes questions and answers do not get fully "registered" in some sense; when they finally do, that changes their datestamp and that is when a notification goes out.

(For reference, my previous question is available [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5673).)

Comment: Can you point us to the question that indicates that all the answers were posted yesterday, but you're sure that they were posted earlier?

Answer (score 2):

The system randomly bumps questions to the home page. I assume this is one of them and in the database it is to the date and time of the bump. Possibly the e-mail being sent is looking at the wrong date, since the questions displayes the original post date.

Edit: As per Jeff - The system will only bump questions without an accepted answer.
Edit: As per mmeyrs - The system will only bump questions without an upvoted answer.

Comment: randomly bumps *unanswered* questions, you mean

Comment: The system will only bump questions without an *upvoted* answer, you mean.

Comment: While I maintain there is a problem with the email, that was the subject of my previous question (see link above). This question is focused on the fact that both a question and all its answers show a creation date on the web page that is several days after they were actually created.